# Append dns suffixes via windows command prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, command-line, dns

At my work, we have two connection specific DNS suffixes. lhs.local and cis.local. I'm trying to write a batch file that will take care of a lot of the common administrative tasks that need done when we deploy a computer, and appending these is one of those tasks.

Is there a command to do this programatically?

Comment: Why are you (ab?)using Zeroconf TLDs?

Comment: Please don't get me started, lol. Why am I the one who pioneered our imaging initiative when I'm just tier 2 support?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Via [this post](http://option9.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-add-dns-suffix-from-command.html)

> In order to add a DNS suffix to a TCP/IP connection remotely, all you need is a list of IP addresses and the following command:

```
wmic /USER:administrator /PASSWORD:adminpassword /node:@c:\iplist.txt nicconfig call SetDNSSuffixSearchOrder (mydomain.com)
```

> where `C:\iplist.txt` contains a list of IP addresses, line separated.

Another way is to add via [the registry](http://windows-server-howto.com/2009/05/02/windows-server-2008-core-how-to-set-dns-suffix-via-command-line/)

```
reg add HKLM\System\currentcontrolset\services\tcpip\parameters /v “NV Domain” /d “mydomain.com” /f
```

There's a [Microsoft KB entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275553) for the same as well.

Comment: Using the reg method above did not work for me. So I read the KB link which talks about setting the value name to "SearchList" not, e.g. "NV Domain".   Using /v SearchList worked (note it will clobber any existing domains so be sure to have them in the /d list.

Answer (score 2):

Based off of Sathya's answer and other resources, I wrote this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Input here the additional suffix
set suffix=your.own.suffix

:: Get existing DNS suffixes
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2* delims= " %%A in (`reg QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /V SearchList ^| findstr REG_SZ`) do ( 
    set OLD_DNS=%%C
)

:: Check if it starts with our suffix
set OK=NO
FOR /F "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%A in ("%OLD_DNS%") do (
    if "%%A" == "%suffix%" set OK=YES
)

:: Add our suffix first if it's not there
if "%OK%" == "NO" (
    echo Conf KO: %OLD_DNS%
    reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters /V SearchList /D "%suffix%,%OLD_DNS%" /F
) else (
    echo Conf OK: %OLD_DNS%
)

ipconfig /flushdns
```